# finding files | mv to one dir level up

Tags: bash, shell, xargs, mv

I'm finding mp3 and mp3.md5 files and moving them one directory level higher. How would one indicate the mv target path?

Found: http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/howto-linux-unix-find-move-all-mp3-file.html which sort of helps -- file structure is below. Running script from $LOCATION.

```
|-- 681506b
|   |-- 681506b.xml
|   `-- Web_Copy
|       |-- 681506b_01.mp3
|       `-- 681506b_01.mp3.md5
DESIRED STRUCTURE AFTER DELETING 'Web_Copy' dir:
|-- 681506b
|   |--681506b.xml
|   |--681506b_01.mp3
|   |--681506b_01.mp3.md5

LOCATION="/var/www/web/html/testdata/"
DIRLIST=`ls -x`
for DIR in $DIRLIST
do
  if [ -d "$DIR" ]
   then
   find . -name "*.mp3*" -type f -print0|xargs -0L1 mv {} $LOCATION$DIR
  fi
done

ERROR: mv: target ./681506b/Web_Copy/681506b_01.mp3 is not a directory
S/B:  mv /var/www/web/html/testdata/681506b/
REPLACED mv with echo: 
{} /var/www/web/html/testdata/680593a./681506b/Web_Copy/681506b_01.mp3
```

Thx

Comment: Can you post the desired directory structure after the script is run?

Comment: Can you replace `mv` with `echo` and print the result?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

It can be something like this (not tested)

```
for i in $( find $LOCATION -type d -name 'Web_Copy' ); do 
  mv $i/* $i/.. && rmdir $i
done
```

Comment: Ok, I did most simple example possible. And, yes, I didn't handle empty spaces, it's needed extra effort to handle other situations... But, example sent by OP should work OK. Do you mind to send your answer, so that we can learn from it ?

Comment: This definitely works, also, and takes care of the other task of deleting the directory -- exactly as written in your post. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Try changing your `find` command to

```
find . -name '*.mp3*' -type f -print0 | xargs -0 -I list mv list ${LOCATION}${DIR}
```

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't just this work?

```
find . -name '*.mp3*' -type f -execdir mv -nv -- {} .. \;
```

This will find all the files (`-type f`) with `.mp3` in their name. For each such file, it will run *from the directory they are in* the command `mv {} ..` (where `{}` is replaced by the file's name). That's the use of `-execdir` instead of `-exec`.

Look:

```
gniourf@somewhere$ mkdir Test && cd Test
gniourf@somewhere$ mkdir -p 681506b{,/Web_Copy}; touch 681506b/{681506b.xml,Web_Copy/681506b.mp3{,.md5}}
gniourf@somewhere$ tree
.
`-- 681506b
    |-- 681506b.xml
    `-- Web_Copy
        |-- 681506b.mp3
        `-- 681506b.mp3.md5

2 directories, 3 files
gniourf@somewhere$ find . -name '*.mp3*' -type f -execdir mv -nv -- {} .. \;
`./681506b.mp3' -> `../681506b.mp3'
`./681506b.mp3.md5' -> `../681506b.mp3.md5'
gniourf@somewhere$ tree
.
`-- 681506b
    |-- 681506b.mp3
    |-- 681506b.mp3.md5
    |-- 681506b.xml
    `-- Web_Copy

2 directories, 3 files
gniourf@somewhere$
```

Comment: Indeed this does work: find . -name '*.wav*' -type f -execdir mv -v -- {} .. \;
 although I do not have the n option

Comment: @edroms The `-n` option is just the _no clobber_ option: it's security switch to not overwrite existing files that is good to use in testing environments. Highly optional if you know what you're doing!

Comment: Incidentally, thanks for the nicely illustrated solution. The -n option is not even available in my bash shell. It's Redhat 5.